# Intentionally get app rejected at app-store approval

Tags: ios, app-store

We have an iOS App which has 3 build configurations: "Debug", "Release" *and* "ReleaseWithGodMode" (must be compiled in Release Mode).

Question is: How can we assure that "ReleaseWithGodMode" never accidentally gets approved by Apple to the App Store (because release code can pass through)?
(Should never happen, but the actual submitting to the app store is not in our hands and we already had some miscommunications.)

We already thought of something like this: `#if GOD_MODE ... private API call`. But relying on Apple being 100% thorough on every tiny little private API call isn't good enough for us.
What other ways are there (preferable in code)?

Comment: Why not have a "god mode" dialog that requires some sort of passcode and if the code isn't entered in 10 seconds or so, call `abort()`. This should result in a rejection because the reviewer won't have the code and the app will crash.

Comment: This ideas sadly won't work, the customer wants this "ReleaseWithGodMode" as close to the store version as it can get, including the icon and any dialogs (only except the hidden god mode dialog).

Comment: It’s a pretty problem, but it isn’t a programming problem and no one knows what Apple will do. Human engineering and prognostication are not Stack Overflow topics.

Comment: "it isn’t a programming problem". I disagree strongly. @Arik Segal answer is a line of code, very promising and I added it, because it will work most likely and is better than relying on nobody making a mistake, ever. Following your logic all discussions around the app-store tag discussing issues with approval are invalid and should be removed from stackoverflow.

Comment: You need to listen to Paulw11's answer and simply tell the customer that this is the way it has to be. If you are only adding a dialog to the very beginning of the app, and nothing else changes it really doesn't affect them too much. I think the idea of trying to find something that you can insert into your code that apple will reject is insane and incredibly difficult to control.

Comment: I also agree with matt, I don't see this as a programming problem, I see this as an issue with the customer.

Comment: “Following your logic all discussions around the app-store tag discussing issues with approval are invalid and should be removed from stackoverflow” Indeed. Such questions are usually either about interpreting Apple’s rejection letter, which is a matter of learning to read, or about what Apple will do, which involves second guessing an arbitrary and capricious human agent. As is this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app doesn't use the IDFA (identifier for advertisers), you can implement a call that reads this key. This will get the app rejected.

Comment: Sounds nice, but it's not an automatic solution, is it? This only fails if we really don't use any ads anywhere.

Our first versions of the App have already passed Apples tests and are now not that thoroughly tested anymore. So, couldn't they just let it through, because there's no human tester who recognizes the missing ads?

Comment: It all depends on wether you answer YES or NO when asked "Does this app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)?" while submitting. If you answer NO and the app contains a code that reads the IDFA, the app is rejected, and you receive a message that asks you to clarify why the IDFA is being read. I believe this is automatic, but I can't tell for sure.